# Re-size rectangles to fit row, but keep proportions

Tags: php, javascript, math, language-agnostic, rectangles

Basically I want to turn this:

[image]

Into this:

[image]

Tried `diff = actual_row_width - max_row_width / number_of_items;`, then substract `diff` from each rectangle but it doesn't seem to keep the ratio :(

Comment: How are you obtaining the width of those elements?

Comment: Keep in mind that those element has **margins**, are you taking it in account?

Comment: How about using percentage widths?

Comment: tx edsioufi that worked! why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: @Alex Posted an answer with additional method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diff is a weighted sum in regard to the width of each of the items. You can't just substract the same amount from every item, but you should divide it according to the relative width of each. Try, for each rectangle:

```
diff = (actual_row_width - max_row_width) * actual_rect_width / actual_row_width
```

You could also reason in percentages and calculate each new rectangle width with the following formula:

```
new_rect_width = (actual_rect_width / actual_row_width) * max_row_width
```

with `(actual_rect_width / actual_row_width)` being the percentage of the width of the row each rectangle occupies.

Answer (score 1):

Given

- W = width
- H = height

You want

- NH = New height

Based on this:

- R = Ratio = NW / W

Then

- NH = New height = H * R = H * ( NW / W )

Comment: Did you mean `New Rectangle Width` instead of `New Height`?